# Telerik Treeview DataBinding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I'm having problems data binding multiple tables in one teir of children. So say for instance I have 5 tables.

```
contracts
members
phoneassessments
homeassessments
personalassessments
```

Each Assessment table has the referencing MemberID and I need to print all three types of assessments in the tiers directly under Members, in other words to look like this.

```
Contract 1
    Member 1
        Home Assessment 1
        Home Assessment 2
        Phone Assessment 1
        Personal Assessment 1
        etc
    Member 2
```

The code I have is...

```
Html.Telerik().TreeView()
   .Name("TreeName")
   .BindTo(Model, mappings =>
     {
       mappings.For<SMTXEFMVCModel.Contract>(binding => binding
         .ItemDataBound((item, contract) =>
           {
             item.Text = contract.Description;
             item.SpriteCssClasses = ("icon-contracts");
           })
           .Children(Contract => Contract.Members));
       mappings.For<SMTXEFMVCModel.Member>(binding => binding
         .ItemDataBound((item, member) =>
           {
             item.Text = member.FirstName + " " + member.LastName;
             item.SpriteCssClasses = ("icon-members");
        }));
     })
    )
```

So my question is, what comes next? What's the syntax?

I can't help but think it will look something like this.

```
Html.Telerik().TreeView()
   .Name("TreeName")
   .BindTo(Model, mappings =>
     {
       mappings.For<SMTXEFMVCModel.Contract>(binding => binding
         .ItemDataBound((item, contract) =>
           {
             item.Text = contract.Description;
             item.SpriteCssClasses = ("icon-contracts");
           })
           .Children(Contract => Contract.Members));
       mappings.For<SMTXEFMVCModel.Member>(binding => binding
         .ItemDataBound((item, member) =>
           {
             item.Text = member.FirstName + " " + member.LastName;
             item.SpriteCssClasses = ("icon-members");
           {)
           .Children(Members => Members.Assessments));
        mappings.For<(SMTXEFMVCModel.HomeAssessments,SMTXEFMVCModel.PhoneAssessments,
                      SMTXEFMVCModel.PersonalAssessments)>(binding => binding
         .ItemDataBound((item, assessments) =>
           {
             item.Text = HomeAssessments.AssessmentID.ToString()
             item.Text = PhoneAssessments.AssessmentID.ToString()
             item.Text = PersonalAssessments.AssessmentID.ToString()
        }));
     })
    )
```

Here's the relevant ActionResult for my controller

```
  public ActionResult TreeView()
  {
    var ctx = new SMTXContext();
    var Contracts = ctx.Contracts.ToList();
    return View(Contracts);
  }
```

which I use in my view as an IEnumerable to Strongly type the tables from the model.  (The below line is the first line in my view.

```
@model IEnumerable<SMTXEFMVCModel.Contract>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning, this "solution" isn't using the databinding version of the telerik treeview, but for anyone seeking to nest multiple tables into a single tier in the treeview, it seems to be a likely candidate.

```
@(

Html.Telerik().TreeView()
    .Name("SeniorMetrix")
    .Items(member => {
      foreach (var member1 in members)
            member.Add()
            .Text(member1.FirstName.ToString())
            .SpriteCssClasses("icon-members")
            .Items(occurance =>
            {
            //lets print In-Home Assessments first
            foreach (var inhomeassessment1 in inHomeAssessments)
              if (inhomeassessment1.MemberID == member1.MemberID)
              {
                occurance.Add()
                .Text("In-Home Assessment #" + inhomeassessment1.InHomeAssessmentID.ToString())
                .SpriteCssClasses("icon-assessments");
              }
            //now we print Telephonic Assessments
            foreach (var telephonicassessment1 in telephonicAssessments)
              if (telephonicassessment1.MemberID == member1.MemberID)
              {
                occurance.Add()
                .Text("Telephonic Assessment #" + telephonicassessment1.TelephonicAssessmentID.ToString())
                .SpriteCssClasses("icon-phone");
              }
            //finally, let's print Episodes
            foreach (var episode1 in episodes)
              if (episode1.MemberID == member1.MemberID)
              {
                occurance.Add()
                .Text("Episode #" + episode1.EpisodeID.ToString())
                .SpriteCssClasses("icon-episodes")
                .Items(assessment =>
                  {
                    foreach (var assessment1 in Episodes)
                      if (assessment1.EpisodeID == episode1.EpisodeID)
                      {
                        if (assessment1.AssessmentTypeID == 1)
                        {
                          assessment.Add()
                        .Text("Admission Assessment #" + afeassessment1.AssessmentID.ToString())
                        .SpriteCssClasses("icon-assessment");
                        }
                        if (assessment1.AssessmentTypeID == 2)
                        {
                          assessment.Add()
                        .Text("Interum Assessment #" + assessment1.AssessmentID.ToString())
                        .SpriteCssClasses("icon-assessment");
                        }
                        if (assessment1.AssessmentTypeID == 3)
                        {
                          assessment.Add()
                        .Text("Discharge Assessment #" + assessment1.AssessmentID.ToString())
                        .SpriteCssClasses("icon-assessment");
                        }
                        if (assessment1.AssessmentTypeID == 4)
                        {
                          assessment.Add()
                        .Text("Followup Assessment #" + assessment1.AssessmentID.ToString())
                        .SpriteCssClasses("icon-assessment");
                        }
                      }
                });
          }});
     }))
```

Comment: That's pretty crafty of you, good thinking on conditionals. Just glad you found someway of making it work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Provided your classes have the correct relationship with each other, It should be as simple as:

```
Html.Telerik().TreeView() 
            .Name("TreeName") 
            .BindTo(Model, mappings =>  
            { 
                mappings.For<SMTXEFMVCModel.Contract>(binding => binding 
                        .ItemDataBound((item, contract) => 
                        { 
                            item.Text = contract.Description;
                            item.SpriteCssClasses = ("icon-contracts");
                        }) 
                        .Children(contract => contract.Members)); 
                mappings.For<SMTXEFMVCModel.Member>(binding => binding 
                        .ItemDataBound((item, member) => 
                        { 
                            item.Text = member.FirstName + " " + member.LastName;
                            item.SpriteCssClasses = ("icon-members");
                        }) 
                        .Children(member => member.Assessments)); 
                mappings.For<MSMTXEFMVCModel.Assessments>(binding => binding 
                        .ItemDataBound((item, assessments) => 
                        { 
                            item.Text = assessments.AssessmentType;
                            ...
                        }));
            })
```

I say it should be because the exact functionality of Telerik controls tends to get "hazy" as you push the normal boundaries, especially newer ones like MVC controls.

I'm sure you've already looked at the examples [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview), but there is nothing in the documentation showing an exact example of how to do what you're trying to do. I've gotten this to work using the above code, but my model and classes may not be set up the same way yours are.

Comment: That would list all the assessments for the respective member (which would be great if I stored all of my assessments in one table, but I'm looking at pulling 3 different tables worth of assessments (phone, telephonic, personal) into that one tier. I would need mappings for all three.. I'll edit my post to show what I feel it probably will look like though I can't get it to work.

Comment: That seems like it could work provided your Model is setup correctly for Members.Assessments. Could you post more info on the structure of your Model?

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to know about it? I'm fairly new to some of this terminology. You want table names, relationships (1 to many), class names created from the model in Entity Framework?

Comment: Yeah, the EF info. Does every table have it's own class? and it's own context? What displays when you implement your updated code?

Comment: Every table does have it's own class. Every table does not have it's own context (this would be defined in the controller?) currently in the controller I pass the first context used in the treeview (contract) which still let's me drill down as far as I want. I'll update the post with the controller ActionResult for the treeview. The updated code won't debug, the syntax for the multiple for mappings is very wrong. :(

Comment: Okay, unfortunately this isn't going to work with your current configuration. I created a forum post so I could get confirmation from one of their reps, you can see it [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/general/telerik-treeview-databinding.aspx). Unless you can change the configuration of your tables, you may have to use something besides Telerik. As much as these controls cost, you would think it would have this ability. I'm kind of surprised, but at least we know for sure now, sorry.

Comment: I very much appreciate all your help! I had posted another similar typic on Telerik's forums and never got any feedback. Though I wasn't able to accomplish this via the binding methods, using standard conditional logic I was able to do it with the standard adding. I'll post it here and though it's a bit more lenghty, it does allow you to utilize the telerik controls and pull multiple tables in to a single tier.  P.S. I imagine this conditional logic is pretty similar to C# or VB's (relation.Add()) function which is almost a FK/PK relationship... Thanks again for your help Roy!